# How to apply format to non-contigous cells range in the VBA macro (Word)?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to perform some simple tasks on the rectangular region of a table in the MS Word document. Let's say, it contains 10 columns and 20 rows. And I need, for example, to center text in cells starting column 2, row 3 up to column 8, row 18. I tried to get a range which starts and ends at the positions specified, but it includes, for example, cells from columns 9 and 10 and rows from 3 up to 17. And corresponding cells from the leftmost columns. On the other hand, if I call the `Select` method of this range, it selects a rectangular region as I desired. But, I don't want to use selections because they make a text flickering.

As a solution, I iterate through these cells, but it takes a long time.

Comment: If you show what you tried it typically will get you more responses here....

Comment: @TimWilliams, actually, I could get the `Range` of non-contiguous cells. Like the `Selection` if you select couple of cells in a table.

Answer (score 2):

«As a solution, I iterate through these cells, but it takes a long time.»

The code below, including the error-checking, takes well under 1 second for a single table:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim eTime As Single: eTime = Timer
Dim Tbl As Table, r As Long, Rng As Range
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  With Tbl
    If .Rows.Count > 17 Then
      If .Columns.Count > 7 Then
        For r = 3 To 18
          Set Rng = .Cell(r, 2).Range
          With Rng
            .End = .Rows(1).Cells(8).Range.End
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
          End With
        Next
      End If
    End If
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
eTime = (Timer - eTime + 86400) Mod 86400 ' Just in case execution time spans midnight
MsgBox "Execution took " & Format(eTime / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

Comment: For sure! But, what if we are talking about dozens of tables?

Comment: In a document with 200 tables, all of which required reformatting, the revised code I've posted above takes 5 seconds on my laptop. Hardly what I'd call 'a long time' given the work involved (22,400 cells to reformat).